# android - how to remove the view of linear layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

In my application i am adding the view dynamically to the linear layout. each view consists of one button if you click on that then view will be deleted. How to refresh the linear layout? because when i removed any view then the view's positions will be changed.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
LinearLayout ll = findViewById(R.id.yourLinearLayout);
```

To remove any view you can use

```
ll.removeView(view)// to remove particular view
ll.removeViewAt(position);// to remove view from particular position
```

Use following logic to remove any view from layout

```
ll.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        ll.removeView(view);
    }
});
```

Comment: why you didn't use 'removeAllViews()' like this: ll.removeAllViews();

Answer (score 6):

You question is not that clear. But you could try setting the view as visibility = gone.

Answer (score 4):

layout.removeAllViewsInLayout();
layout.invalidate();

I hope this help

Answer (score 2):

**How to refresh the linear layout?**

```
linearLayoutObject.invalidate()
```

**How to remove item from the linear layout?**

```
linearLayoutObject.removeView(View view);
```

or

```
linearLayoutObject.removeViewAt(int index);
```

I hope it helps..

Comment: Please stop suggesting edits where you "fix" links. Replacing link text with "Link1" or something similar is a terrible edit, and you're making work for people who have to fix them. See my edit for how links are *actually* supposed to work: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8741270/229044

Answer (score 2):

By removing or adding views the linearlayout has to measure and layout all its children again which is why they move. You could simply try setting the visibility to invisible.

```
myLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

any view set to invisible still retains its size and positioning in the layout but can no longer be seen.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

after remove?

Comment: oh, forgot that you creating elements dynamicaly

Answer (score 0):

use listview with Adapter to fill the data dynamically (because that's what for they are made) and whenever your data or UI gets changed create new adapter (data set) and notify the adapter about change.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Use linearLayout.removeView(View view); 
It would refresh automaically.