# Two conflicting statements for google static map usage

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I found two conflicting statements regarding the limit usage of google stati map api

According to [this link](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#usage_pricing), 25 000 usage limit are allowed per day

According to [this link](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Limits) 1000 usage limit are allowed per day.

Now I am confuse which one is correct

Answer (score 2):

25000 is the limit per site, 1000 is the limit per viewer. Site is tracked by URL or developer key. Viewer is tracked by ip address. My browser loading your page would count 1 against your site limit, and 1 against my ip address viewer limit.

To get an API key, you can apply here:
https://code.google.com/apis/console/

Comment: but static map api v2 does not require any api key. I want to make one website in which there is a link and when user click on that link, the request for static map api is send. The request is sent from user browser and does not arrive to my server. So this request will be counted in site limit or viewer limit or both ?

Answer (score 0):

The limits both apply. 25000 for your application, 1000 per user, as said by Mano Marks.
But if I unterstand you right, you just want to link to a map? Why don't you just use a [standard google maps link](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY)? Then you wouldn't have any limits.

And still, if you just link to the staticmaps call (e.g. [this example](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=14&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap&markers=color%3ablue|label%3aS|40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color%3agreen|label%3aG|40.711614,-74.012318&markers=color%3ared|color%3ared|label%3aC|40.718217,-73.998284&sensor=false)), your application has nothing to do with the staticmap call - its the users decision to open it. I guess there won't be any limits for that. (But perhaps they DO track the referrer and apply the limit for your page.)